# javascript isn't working on html

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to both html and javascript

I copied the these codes from codecademy, but they are not working well. I hope someone can explain to me why isn't the javascript working in my html. Thank you so much!

index.html

```
<html>
<head>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400;300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>

</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">

  <!-- Menu icon -->
  <div class="icon-close">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
  </div>

  <!-- Menu -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Main body -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="icon-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var main=function(){

$('.icon-menu').click(function(){
    $('.menu').animate({left:'0px'},200);
    $('body').animate({left:'285px'},200);
    });

$('.icon-close').click(function(){
    $('.menu').animate({left:'-285px'},200);
    $('body').animate({left:'0px'},200);
});
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

The code you have there in `app.js` is written using `jQuery`.
Even though you need `jQuery`, the `$`, i your `app.js` you have included your `script tag` for including `jQuery` after `app.js`.

Therefore when your `app.js` loads, you still do not have `jQuery` so your script fails.

The solution is to include `jQuery` first and then including your `app.js`.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Problem is solved.

I changed this
<script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
to

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>